# 'NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm getting a compiler error: 'NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft' undeclared (first use in this function) on this line of code:

```
[searchTableView removeRowsAtIndexes:[[searchTableView selectedRowIndexes] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft]];
```

But the most weird thing is that I couldn't find any example on internet. (just 5 results with Google). What's wrong with this method ?

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be UITableViewAnimation in stead of NSTableViewAnimation?

Comment: @Aberrant I'm on mac http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> [searchTableView removeRowsAtIndexes:[[searchTableView selectedRowIndexes] withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft]];
> ```

Your bracket nesting is wrong:

- `[searchTableView removeRowsAtIndexes:`

  - `[`

    - `[searchTableView selectedRowIndexes]`
  - `withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft]`
- `];`

It's syntactically legal, but I don't think you mean to send a `withAnimation:` message to the index set, nor to pass the return value of that message (if it had one) as the index set to `removeRowsAtIndexes:`.

> I'm getting a compiler error: 'NSTableViewAnimationSlideLeft' undeclared (first use in this function)

It was introduced in 10.7, so make sure you're using the 10.7 SDK.

Don't forget to make this code conditional if you're supporting 10.5 or 10.6.

Comment: How do I delete a row in 10.5 and 10.6 ?

Comment: @Patrick: Send the table view a `reloadData` message. (`noteNumberOfRowsChanged` *might* work, but based on the description in the documentation, I wouldn't count on it.) The table view will ask the data source or bound array what has changed.